# HTML Textarea 'Enter' adding \n when I am needing \r\n

Tags: javascript, jquery

We have users who are using a substringAfter('\n\r\n') on a record field.

We have a UI with an HTML textarea for said field that the user can type stuff into, then save and the JSON.stringified information be sent to the controller.

However, when typing into the text area, 'Enter' is just treated as \n instead of \r\n... In Salesforce, 'Enter' is treated as \r\n, so their trigger works fine when doing things through Salesforce UI.

Can textarea's handling of 'Enter' be modified to make it \r\n? Or what would be the best approach to deal with this issue? A global replace of \n with \r\n?

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: you can use YOURSTRING.replaceAll('\n','\r\n');

Comment: Yeah, this seems to be about the only route to go... However, to make sure extra \r\n are not added, I had to first replace all \r\n with just \n, then replace all \n with \r\n (since I could have \r\n in the string).